# A re-open request for an improved question

Tags: support, reopen-closed

This question: [How to find the closest set of numbers from a given one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18688901/how-to-find-the-closest-set-of-numbers-from-a-given-one#comment27541075_18688901) has been vastly improved by the OP since it was closed.

I'm not sure how long it usually takes for a question to go through the reopen queue, but it's been 12 hours now.

Could a few high-rep users take a look at it, and if they feel it appropriate, vote to reopen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I cast a reopen vote, and it looked like enough other people did too.

It's been reopened.